# How To Get Percent Uptime Using Puppet Facts API

Tags: puppet

I am able to get the current uptime of a given set of nodes using the [Puppet Facts REST Endpoint](https://puppet.com/docs/puppetdb/latest/api/query/v4/facts.html) like this:

```
curl -X GET https://puppet:8081/pdb/query/v4/facts --data-urlencode 'query=["=", "name", "uptime"]' -k -H "X-Authentication: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

That provides a response that looks like this

```
{"certname":"xyz","environment":"production","name":"uptime","value":"107 days"}
```

But, it doesn't tell me the previous uptime, and so I don't have a way of calculating the downtime of this Node.  Is there a way to use Puppet facts to see historical data over time such that I could see over the course of a given timeframe that a Node had x seconds of total uptime and y seconds of total downtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, is the short answer.
Facts on the server are primarily there to provide Puppet with the information it needs to compile a catalog, it's not designed to give historical data, just a "this is what the server looks like right now".

The command you're looking for on linux is probably `last reboot`.

If you want to extract data from a machine remotely using Puppet it would be much more appropriate to use Puppet tasks, if you have Puppet Enterprise, if not the same functionality is available using Puppet Bolt tasks.

### On Puppet Enterprise

Just create a tasks directory in your module and drop a script in it to do what you want.
Or use an existing one https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-reboot look in the tasks directory here. On Puppet enterprise you'll be able to see those tasks on the console.

### Bolt

You'll need to install Bolt, you could use the same module above. This is a good guide to getting started with Puppet Bolt.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Z7nYlspUJw